# How do you use the Optional variable in a ternary conditional operator?

Tags: swift, ternary-operator

I want to use an Optional variable with the ternary conditional operator but it is throwing error this error: *optional cannot be used as boolean.* What am I doing wrong?

```
var str1: String?
var myBool:Bool
myBool = str1 ? true : false
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can not assign string value to bool but You can check it str1 is nil or not like this way :

```
myBool = str1 != nil ? true : false
print(myBool)
```

It will print false because str1 is empty.

Comment: You don't need the conditional expression, just do: `myBool = str1 != nil`

Answer (score 71):

Nil Coalescing Operator can be used as well.
The code below uses the ternary conditional operator and forced unwrapping (a!) to access the value wrapped inside a when a is not nil, and to return b otherwise

Normal Ternary Operator :

`output = a != nil ? a! : b`
[Apple Developer Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) : Please refer to [Demo Link](http://swiftstub.com/776169432/?v=gm)

In Swift 1.2 & 2, above line of code is replaced by a shorter format:

```
output = a ?? b
```

[Demo Link](http://swiftstub.com/178691525/?v=beta) : The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil.

Answer (score 5):

This even works well if the value you want is a property or result of a function call on an optional (in Swift 3.0):

```
return peripheral?.connected ?? false
```

Comment: that's not answering the same question, because you assume we want the value - if it exists, and nil otherwise. While we want two different expressions - based on an arbitrary conditionals. something like  a>3  ? (4+7) : (6/4) in C.

Answer (score 5):

> [Ternary operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) operate on three targets. Like C, Swift has only one
>   ternary operator, the ternary conditional operator (a ? b : c).

Example usage on `tableView` -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return section == 2 ?  4 :  1
}
```

indicates if section equal to 2 then it return 4 otherwise 1 on false.

Comment: This answer doesn't address OP's specific requirement for Optionals though

Answer (score 2):

To add on the already very good answers, sometimes you need the convenience of the ternary operator but also need to perform changes on the wrapped value, such as;

```swift
var fullName = lastName != nil ? "\(firsName) \(lasName!)" : firstName
```

But you don't want to force unwrap (even though this situation would be fine).

Then you can actually use `Optional.map`:

```swift
var fullName = lastName.map({ "\(firstName) \($0)" }) ?? firstName
```

The completion block passed to `.map` is only called if the wrapped value (`$0`) is not `nil`. Otherwise, that function just returns `nil`, which you can then easily coalesce with the `??` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In case the comparison is based on some condition

```
 let sliderValue = Float(self.preferenceData.getLocationRadius().characters.count > 1 ?self.preferenceData.getLocationRadius():"0.1")
```

Here the function getLocationRadius() returns a String. One more thing if we don't put a space between 1 and ? it results in an syntax error