# Assignment in bracket in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Swift beginner is here.
I am reading a textbook of Swift and found a strange expression... what is this code (second "let" line) doing? Please take a look at the thing between equal sign and the UITableVIewCell method.
To me it looks like "c is not nil, it should be optional, and c should be unwrapped...."

(c != nil) ? c!

It is hard for me to search it in the internet (google) because I cannot make a good search keywords in the search engine for the question.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //create cells in table
    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("table_cell")
    let cell = (c != nil) ? c!: UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "table_cell")
return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
let cell = (c != nil) ? c!: UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "table_cell")
```

is demonstrating the ? [ternary operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html).

If `c != nil` then `c!` is returned, else the call is made to `UITableViewCell`.

The code could be simplified to use the shorthand nil coalescing operator:

```
let cell = c ?? UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "table_cell")
```

Similar question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881838/how-do-you-use-the-optional-variable-in-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

Answer (score 1):

It's a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). Normally a bit hard to wrap your head around to begin with. It works like this:

If the (c != nil) is true (i.e. c exists) then `cell == c!` (from the left side of the :). On the other hand, if c *is* nil then (c != nil) returns false, then cell = `UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "table_cell")` from the right side of the colon.

You might want to play around with this in the playground to get a better understanding of how it works:

```
let text = "foo" // try changing this to something else entirely
let output = text == "foo" ? text : "bar"
print(output)
```